# Make WebPartPage editable ONLY by SCA, but personalizable by all in site definition?

Tags: web-part, custom

I'm creating a landing page inside of a site definition.

This landing page will have all blank web part zones.

What I would like to do, is have the zones initially set by someone like a Site Collection Admin, so there are a group of core web parts.

Then the rest of the users can customize the remaining slots themselves.

I'm looking for two options:
One, can the core webparts be locked down, so they always display?
Two, at the very least, can I make a page personalizable while restricting editing?

Comment: Hope this link helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794842/how-to-determine-whether-a-user-can-modify-personalizable-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How skilled are your site collection admins?  Could they edit a page layout using SP Designer?  If so, using a page layout the SCA can add webparts outside of zones and then the end users could customize any webpart zones on the page.